# GCP kubernetes objects monitoring options

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring

We are trying to figure out which monitoring options will be suitable for our environment.

We have two clusters in GCP and we installed Istio (with Helm) in both of them. We are also using Workload Identity and Stackdriver Monitoring.

Now, we would like to create dashboards (or charts) for kubernetes objects (such as, deployments, containers, cronjobs, services, etc.) and want to set alerts on them. So can anyone suggest free monitoring options to achieve these all? We don't want to go with any third party paid software.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `GCP GKE` then default `stack driver logging & monitoring` is best option.

It's free if you are using GCP service and using stack driver monitoring you can monitoring and creat respective dashboards as per need.

For alerts, you can use the `GCP` Uptime check option available in monitoring itself which sends the email. For call alerts, you may have to use some custom or third applications.

You can read more at : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs

Uptime checks : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks

Comment: We are aware about Stackdriver and GCP uptime check options but the point is in GCP we are not getting all required metrics related to kubernetes objects such as, pod_phase, container_restart_count, job_status_succeeded, etc. These metrics can be exported using kube-state metrics, so do we have any other free options like this through which we can have all objects metrics in GCP?